# In general, why would the timing of the same code with MPI change?

Tags: mpi, multidimensional-array, fortran90

I have a serial code that I have parallelize it using MPI in FORTRAN. Without changing the test input, the timing change from one run to the other.
Say run 1 t = 0.75sec
run 2: t = 0.32 sec
Again nothing changes, same input variable, same compiler and same number of porcesses and nodes used.
What could be happening?
Thank you

Comment: Don't make attempts to draw conclusions from 2 data points.  Run the program at least 10 times, calculate the mean execution time and std deviation (or other measure of variance if you want).  Then report back.  When you write *nothing changes* are you certain that this is true ?  Is it possible, for example, that other activity on your hardware makes your program wait for i/o resources, or some other shared facility ?

Comment: Do you measure time from starting `mpirun`/`mpiexec` until it finishes? Starting time, especially with some MPI implementations, might vary wildly. I have seen ranks join in as late as several seconds after the launcher was started (especially on very large jobs where many network paths have to probed initially).

Comment: I am extremely hesitant to compare the runtime of two MPI programs until the total runtime is "significant"...in most cases my personal benchmark is >1000 seconds.  Below that, "absolute" times can be safely compared, but not "percentages" or "factors."  In "short" duration jobs, a number of factors that are not directly related to MPI can dominate the timing data:  job startup time, file I/O, user authentication, interconnect setup, and so on.  HPM's comment about timing and analyzing multiple runs is also a good place to start.

Comment: @Mark: I will do as you suggested, that sounds like a good idea.